# What is the meaning of {...this.props} in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

What is the meaning of

```
{...this.props}
```

I am trying to use it like that

```
 <div {...this.props}> Content Here </div>
```

Answer (score 254, accepted):

It's called [spread attributes](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-spread.html) and its aim is to make the passing of props easier.

Let us imagine that you have a component that accepts N number of properties. Passing these down can be tedious and unwieldy if the number grows.

```
<Component x={} y={} z={} />
```

So instead do this, wrap them up in an object and use the spread notation

```
var props = { x: 1, y: 1, z:1 };
<Component {...props} />
```

which will unpack it into the props on your component, i.e., you "never" use `{... props}` inside your `render()` function, only when you pass the props down to another component. Use your unpacked props as normal `this.props.x`.

Comment: Just to add, it can help to think of it as a replacement to `this.transferPropsTo` which was deprecated in React 0.12.x and will be removed in 0.13.x.  It of course allows much more advanced usage however simply translating React 0.11.x's `this.transferPropsTo(<Foo />)` to `<Foo {...this.props} />` is most useful for people making that transition.

Comment: Good awnser, but 'you "never" use {... props} inside your render() function, only when you pass the props down to another component.' Is a very confusing term of phrase. 

Recommend to rewrite is as

"You only use  {... props} inside your render() when you pass the props down to another component." for clarity.

Answer (score 27):

It's ES6 [`Spread_operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [`Destructuring_assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
<div {...this.props}>
  Content Here
</div>
```

It's equal to `Class Component`

```
const person = {
    name: "xgqfrms",
    age: 23,
    country: "China"
};

class TestDemo extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {name, age, country} = {...this.props};
        // const {name, age, country} = this.props;
        return (
          <div>
              <h3> Person Information: </h3>
              <ul>
                <li>name={name}</li>
                <li>age={age}</li>
                <li>country={country}</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <TestDemo {...person}/>
    , mountNode
);
```

[image]

---

or `Function component`

```
const props = {
    name: "xgqfrms",
    age: 23,
    country: "China"
};

const Test = (props) => {
  return(
    <div
        name={props.name}
        age={props.age}
        country={props.country}>
        Content Here
        <ul>
          <li>name={props.name}</li>
          <li>age={props.age}</li>
          <li>country={props.country}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Test {...props}/>
        <hr/>
        <Test 
            name={props.name}
            age={props.age}
            country={props.country}
        />
    </div>
    , mountNode
);
```

[image]

### refs

- https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/
- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 2):

It is ES-6 feature. It means you extract all the properties of props in 
`div.{... }`

operator is used to extract properties of an object.

Answer (score 2):

It will compile to this:

```
React.createElement('div', this.props, 'Content Here');
```

As you can see above, it passes all it's props to the `div`.

Answer (score 2):

You will use props in your child component

for example

if your now component props is

```
{
   booking: 4,
   isDisable: false
}
```

you can use this props in your child compoenet

```
 <div {...this.props}> ... </div>
```

in you child component, you will receive all your parent props.

Comment: Good answer but would be even better if you included an explanation about what props are for.

Answer (score 1):

this.props is the object which contains the Attributes which we have passed to the parent component

Answer (score 0):

we can pass props for example in nextJS with :

```
            <Component {...{
              props,
              allCount: count?.lenght,
            }} />
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).