# what are all the properties that has been passed as props in this es6 destructuring

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What are all the properties that has been passed as props in this es6 destructure ?

```
const {
      day,
      day: {
        date,
        isCurrentMonth,
        isToday,
        number
      },
      select,
      selected
    } = this.props;
```

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452358/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-props-in-reactjs

Comment: Those properties are not being "passed" to the destructuring functionality. You are destructuring `this.props` (from the React Component) into tiny variables.

Answer (score 2):

Your props object is something like this

```
this.props = {
  day: {
    date,
    isCurrentMonth,
    isToday,
    number
  },
  select,
  selected
}
```

with `props` `day` which is of `type` object, select which could be number, string, boolean or something else can't really the type from the information you provide, and `selected` as our last prop.

To destructure, this.props, you do something like this:

```
 const { day, select, selected } = this.props;
```

Since `day` is also an `object` you can further destructure it like this:

```
const { date, isCurrentMonth, isToday, number } = day
```

You can as well call the day object properties on the `day` object itself

```
const date = day.date;
const  isCurrentMonth = day.isCurrentMonth;
```

That piece of code above is similar to the destructuring mentioned earlier.

Simply put by destructuring, you are storing object properties in other variables for ease of access