# Understanding destructive assignment of a component in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following React component:

```
export default function AuthExample () {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <AuthButton/>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/public">Public Page</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/protected">Protected Page</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <Route path="/public" component={Public} />
        <Route path="/login" component={ Login } />
        <PrivateRoute path='/protected' component={ Protected } />
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

My difficulty is understanding the parameters passed to the  component and how it is being unboxed in the function that creates this component , below is the function:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
    fakeAuth.isAuthenticated === true
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect to={{
          pathname: '/login',
          state: { from: props.location }
        }} />
  )} />
)
```

So what exactly is `component: Component` here ? and is the ES-5 [destructive assignment](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment) ?  so then what exact is `<Component {...props} />` in the end ?

Comment: It's not called "destructive assignment". It's _destructuring assignment_. "destructive" implies that something is destroyed, but in fact destructuring assignment is a useful way to avoid mutating the original object or array. So in a sense it's the opposite of destruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{ component: Component, ...rest }` assigns property `component` to variable `Component`. You can read about destructuring assignments [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names).

In the `<PrivateRoute path='/protected' component={ Protected } />` you pass `Protected` as a `component` property and `Protected` is then referenced as `Component` variable inside `PrivateRoute` component.
<s>This is only for your convenience.</s> This is required by JSX in order to distinguish between standard html elements and user-defined components.

In `<Component {...props} />` the `{...props}` means to take all the key-value pairs from `props` object and pass them to the `Component`. Check out [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28452430/5741378) for better clarification.

In fact, the following line

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => ();
```

means

> from the properties passed to this component take the `component`, store it as `Component` and keep all other properties in `rest` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You first passed to `PrivateRoute` the following two props: `path` and `component`.
What the function header `({ component: Component, ...rest })` means, is that you can pass it an object, and it will look for a property with the key of `component` and store it as `Component`, and the rest of the remaining properties, if any, will be put  into the `rest` object. In this case, your component parameter will be the component `Protected`, which you passed, and the `rest` will contain the `path`.

Regarding `<Component {...props} />`:
It's object destructuring, which basically means, that the `key: value` pairs within that object, in your case `props`, will get enlisted there.

So, with an object:

```
const myProps = {
    name: 'John',
    age: 21
}
```

And used as:

```
<MyComponent { ...myProps } />
```

It's the same as you would do this:

```
<MyComponent name={myProps.name} age={myProps.age} />
```

Comment: "it will look for a property with the key of component and a type of Component" - this is not true. The point of that line is to store a `component` as `Component`. It says nothing about the type of this property.

Comment: You are correct, I was thinking in TS, thank you. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

`{component: Component}` is indeed destructuring assignment, also called ["argument unpacking"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter) in the context of function arguments.

It simply gives the prop `component` a new name `Component` in the scope of this function. JSX syntax requires [all user defined components to be capitalized](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_function_parameter). (`<component />` will not work. Only native dom elements can be lower cased: `<span />` etc.)

While it's syntactically permitted to use any case in prop names (so you could simply use `{ Component }` instead, the convention for props is to use camelCase, following normal javascript convention for DOM attributes and variable names.

So the prop you pass in is called `component`, but inside the component function, it's `Component`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and just to answer the secound part of my question, `Component` is actually `Protected` in the end ?

Comment: Yes, when you pass in `component={ Protected }`, that's what's assigned to `Component` in that instance.